# How to change the order of "messages" in starUML in a communication diagram?

Tags: staruml, communication-diagram

Changing the order of `messages` in a communication diagram in starUML seems impossible. Up until now I've been deleting all the `messages` and adding them back in the right order.

This seems quite a lot of trouble (even for starUML) for a relatively easy task. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the right hand pannel, as for most things in starUML.

[image: screenshot of starUML]

As you can see the messages in this panel are ordered as they're shown on screen. `message1` comes before `message2`. However, I want the order to be different.

You can right click a message and select `move up` or `move down` respectively to change the order.

[image]

After this you have to click back into the diagram to force an update and voilla. The order of the messages is changed and your life is saved.

#### Note

You can't drag the messages around in this right hand panel to change their order. Why not? I don't know... ☹️